# Why isn't my alphabetical input validation working?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm building a registration form with alphabetical input only, and regardless of whether I input an alphabetical or special character, my error message still appears. As it stands, I thought my code would search through the value in `fname`, and if it doesn't match the characters in `ABC`, then it should return `FALSE` and create my error message at the bottom (except my error message appears even when I input an alphabetical character, which I thought should output `TRUE` and not execute the `IF` statement).

What am I doing wrong?

```
// First Name & Last Name Validation

let fname = document.getElementById("fname");
fname.addEventListener("keypress", ABCvalidate);
let ABC = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

function ABCvalidate() {
  if (!ABC.test(fname.value)) {
    document.getElementById("CSerror").innerHTML =
      "No spaces or special characters allowed";
  }
}
```

[image: 1] [image: 2] [image: 3]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the issues i see

1. The [`keypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event) event is deprecated
2. it is fired when a key is pressed down, so before the character has been added to the value of the input element (*and thus on first press the value is empty, and the test is `false`*)
3. you never clear the error message if the value is corrected

You can use the `input` event which will also handle copy/pastes in to the input element.

```js
// First Name & Last Name Validation

let fname = document.getElementById("fname");
fname.addEventListener("input", ABCvalidate);
let ABC = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

function ABCvalidate() {
  const errorElement = document.getElementById("CSerror");
  if (!ABC.test(fname.value)) {
    errorElement.innerHTML = "No spaces or special characters allowed";
  } else {
    errorElement.innerHTML = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="fname" />
<div id="CSerror"></div>
```